# What is the most pythonic way to combine multiple string columns to create a new Pandas series?

Tags: python, string, pandas, merge

I have a large dataframe with each row containing various amounts of text/string data (song lyrics that were webscraped and then split by line '\n'). Some columns have None values because of this. I'd like to combine all the columns that do have a value into 1 column for each row. I've attached a screenshot so you can see what I'm working with(profanity censored).

[image]

Comment: `df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)` should do the trick

Comment: Looks like you have to treat this before actually putting it in a data frame. Why do you split by lines in the first place?

Comment: Let's not forget that being "pythonic" also requires the solution be clear and maintainable as well as concise.  Exploiting the features of python is great, but if you re-read your code six months from now and wonder "it works, but how?" then you have missed the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid NAs, here's a way using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df_with_line_sentences.agg(lambda x: ' '.join(i for i in x if not pd.isna(i)), axis=1)
```